Ada integer text guess error, how to fix?
So I was creating a guessing game for Ada but yeah it doesn't run. The error is in Line 25.
It says
guessing_game.adb:25:26: error: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

procedure Guessing_Game is
   type Number_Range is range 1 .. 100;
   package Random_Number is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Number_Range);
   use Random_Number;

   Generator : Random_Number.Generator;
   Secret_Number : Number_Range;
   Guess : Number_Range;
   Attempts : Integer := 0;
   Last_Guess : Integer := -1;

begin
   Reset(Generator);
   Secret_Number := Random(Generator);

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("1 to 100, if not guessed then byebye system32!");

   loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put("guess NOW:");
      Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Guess);

      if Integer(Guess) = Last_Guess then
         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Try one more before the os is deleted!");
      else
         Attempts := Attempts + 1;
         Last_Guess := Integer(Guess);

         if Guess < Secret_Number then
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("eeeee too smol");
         elsif Guess > Secret_Number then
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("eeeee too big");
         else
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Ok you guessed it in ");
            Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Attempts);
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(" attempts, os wont be removed anymore");
            exit;
         end if;
      end if;
   end loop;
end Guessing_Game;


I already tried changing it to directly pass the guess to get but it doesn't work.

You have specified the variable named Guess to have type  Number_Range, which you have defined as follows:
type Number_Range is range 1 .. 100;

The resulting error messages can help identify the problem:
guessing_game.adb:24:26: error: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
guessing_game.adb:24:26: error: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "Get" declared at a-tiinio.ads:96, instance at a-inteio.ads:18
guessing_game.adb:24:26: error: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "Get" declared at a-tiinio.ads:53, instance at a-inteio.ads:18
guessing_game.adb:24:31: error: expected type "Standard.Integer"
guessing_game.adb:24:31: error: found type "Number_Range" defined at line 6
guessing_game.adb:24:31: error:   ==> in call to "Get" at a-tiinio.ads:62, instance at a-inteio.ads:18

In particular, you attempt to Get the user's Guess using an instance of the generic package Integer_IO that was instantiated using the standard type Integer, permitted here. Number_Range and Integer are not the same type.
One approach is to define Number_Range as a subtype of Integer having the desired range:
subtype Number_Range is Positive range 1 .. 100;

Alternatively, instantiate Integer_IO using your original Number_Range, and use the instance to get the user's guess:
package Range_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO (Number_Range);
…
Range_IO.Get (Guess);

Either way, your program then compiles and runs as expected.

I always find messages like the second two at 24:26 very unhelpful. Remove those two distractions, and the rest make more sense.
